# Change Oracle query to MySQL - syntax error

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have an Oracle query that works on an Oracle database. But when I'm trying to move it over to MySQL, I have syntax error and I can't understand where the error is.

Oracle query:

```
DELETE FROM tec_valid_codes
               WHERE code IN
                        (SELECT a.oldacctnbr
                           FROM tec_onoff_file a,
                                tec_onoff_file b,
                                tec_valid_codes c
                          WHERE     a.curracctnbr = b.curracctnbr
                                AND a.oldacctnbr <> b.oldacctnbr
                                AND a.transtype = 'COMB'
                                AND b.transtype = 'COMB'
                                AND a.oldacctnbr = c.code
                         MINUS
                           SELECT MAX (c.oldacctnbr)
                             FROM tec_valid_codes tvc,
                                  (SELECT a.oldacctnbr, a.curracctnbr
                                     FROM tec_onoff_file a, tec_onoff_file b
                                    WHERE     a.curracctnbr = b.curracctnbr
                                          AND a.oldacctnbr <> b.oldacctnbr
                                          AND a.transtype = 'COMB'
                                          AND b.transtype = 'COMB') c
                            WHERE tvc.code = c.oldacctnbr
                         GROUP BY curracctnbr);
```

And my MySQL query, that is not working:

```
DELETE FROM tec_valid_codes vc
                WHERE vc.code IN
                    (SELECT t1.oldacctnbr FROM
                        (SELECT a.oldacctnbr
                        FROM tec_onoff_file a,
                            tec_onoff_file b,
                            tec_valid_codes c
                        WHERE a.curracctnbr = b.curracctnbr
                        AND a.oldacctnbr <> b.oldacctnbr
                        AND a.transtype = 'COMB'
                        AND b.transtype = 'COMB'
                        AND a.oldacctnbr = c.code) as `t1`
                    WHERE t1.oldacctnbr NOT IN 
                       (SELECT MAX(c.oldacctnbr)
                        FROM tec_valid_codes tvc,
                            (SELECT a.oldacctnbr, a.curracctnbr
                            FROM tec_onoff_file a, tec_onoff_file b
                            WHERE a.curracctnbr = b.curracctnbr
                            AND a.oldacctnbr <> b.oldacctnbr
                            AND a.transtype = 'COMB'
                            AND b.transtype = 'COMB') as `c`
                        WHERE tvc.code = c.oldacctnbr)
                    GROUP BY vc.curracctnbr);
```

I have error at this line:

```
'vc
   WHERE vc.code IN
     (SELECT t1.oldacctnbr FROM
        (SELECT a.oldacctn'
```

I don't see syntax error here. Where I'm wrong? And will my MySQL query work correctly?

**Edited:** My solution:

```
DELETE FROM tec_valid_codes
            WHERE code IN
                (SELECT t1.oldacctnbr FROM
                    (SELECT a.oldacctnbr
                    FROM tec_onoff_file a,
                        tec_onoff_file b,
                        tec_valid_codes c
                    WHERE a.curracctnbr = b.curracctnbr
                    AND a.oldacctnbr <> b.oldacctnbr
                    AND a.transtype = 'COMB'
                    AND b.transtype = 'COMB'
                    AND a.oldacctnbr = c.code) as `t1`)
            AND code NOT IN
                (SELECT t2.oldcode FROM
                   (SELECT MAX(c.oldacctnbr) as oldcode 
                    FROM tec_valid_codes tvc,
                        (SELECT a.oldacctnbr, a.curracctnbr
                        FROM tec_onoff_file a, tec_onoff_file b
                        WHERE a.curracctnbr = b.curracctnbr
                        AND a.oldacctnbr <> b.oldacctnbr
                        AND a.transtype = 'COMB'
                        AND b.transtype = 'COMB') as `c`
                    WHERE tvc.code = c.oldacctnbr
                    GROUP BY curracctnbr) as `t2`);
```

Is it correct query?

Comment: Excatly what error are you getting??

Comment: Exactly:  
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error i
 n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server v
 ersion for the right syntax to use near 'vc
                               WHERE vc.code IN

                                       (SELECT t1.oldacctnbr FROM

                                               (SELECT a.oldacctn' at line 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (at least) a small mistake at the end:

```
GROUP BY vc.curracctnbr
```

Should be something from t1:

```
GROUP BY t1.curracctnbr
```

Comment: Thanks. When I fix it, I found one more.

Comment: @RexHunt :) Your query looks too complicated

Comment: @Multusync I know, but I'm not the author.